# What's a good simple model for wind attacking drone?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to simulate a drone on https://rapier.rs/. My idea is to do an X shaped object, with a force $P$ on each end of the X, always perpendicular to the drone plane.

I want to simulate wind, which I think would be good if it were a $W$ vector force acting on each of the propellers. Or should I just use a force acting on the middle?

Is there a better way?

The goal is to construct a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller to control the drone, so I don't need a very complicated wind model.

[image]

Comment: If the wind has no vertical component (updraft, downdraft), then there is no difference between a wind and flight at the same speed through still air.  It's unclear to me what you're looking for.  Are you already simulating drag?

Comment: @BowlOfRed no, I want to add drag, but I wanted to add sudden wind attacking the drone from different directions to see how the PID system responds. Yes, the wind can have any kind of direction

Comment: http://ai.stanford.edu/~gabeh/papers/ICRA09_AeroEffects.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of the propellers rotate the same direction, when the wind hits them it will create more lift and drag on the side of the propeller that is moving toward the wind. The right propellers will have more lift on the outside blade, and the left propellers will have more lift on the inside blade (for example)

Looking at the torque on the drone about its center of gravity - the outside blades have disproportionately large torque effects due to their increased lever arm, so the asymmetric outside lift will create a rolling action around the wind vector, and the asymmetric outside drag will create a yawing action around the up axis.

That is to say - a simple model looking only at a single force acting on the drone will not capture the full dynamics. Nor will simple forces acting on each propeller.

Comment: I can't assume all propellers rotate in the same direction because this would create torque